# CQWP and ViewFieldOverrides

Tags: content-query-web-part, discussion-board

I'm having trouble with ViewFieldOverrides in CQWP. I'm showing a CQWP that rolls up Discussion Items and the Site they belong to.

I can get my needed properties using @LinkUrl and "URL" as the slot. Then I get the `ProjectProperty.Titl`e for the title of the site they belong to. For the Site Title, I use `ViewFieldOverride`.

My problem is, it kinda broke the @LinkUrl? If I remove the ViewFieldOverride, it works. But the other one doesn't.

How can I get it to work for both?

I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
<property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string">
    <FieldRef Name="URL" Nullable="True" Type="URL"/>
    <FieldRef Name="PublishedLinksURL" Nullable="True" Type="URL"/>
    <ProjectProperty Name="Title" />
</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [ContentByQueryWebPart.ViewFieldsOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.viewfieldsoverride%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property is specified, it **overrides** default list field names used to filter the set of list items. It means all the required fields have to be specified explicitly, in your case it would be:

```
 <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Nullable="True" Type="Text" /><FieldRef ID="{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb}" Nullable="True" Type="Lookup" /><ProjectProperty Name="Title" />]]></property>
```

where Field IDs

```
fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247: Title 
94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb: FileRef
```

Manifest example: aggregating Discussion items

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">Discussions</property>
        <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
        <property name="ContentTypeBeginsWithId" type="string">0x012002</property>
        <property name="SortBy" type="string">{28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f}</property>
        <property name="WebUrl" type="string"></property>
        <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string">108</property>
        <property name="DataMappingViewFields" type="string">{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},Image;{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;</property>
        <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Nullable="True" Type="Text" /><FieldRef ID="{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb}" Nullable="True" Type="Lookup" /><ProjectProperty Name="Title" />]]></property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```